# Ember-Cli: prepend a findAll() query with a prefix

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In one of my routes I need to `findAll()` of user's `Items`, but instead of making the standard `/items` request it has to go to `/my/items`.

My current solution involves:

```
// routes/my/item.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        this.store.unloadAll('item');
        return Ember.$.getJSON('/my/items').then((payload) => {
          this.store.pushPayload(payload);
          return this.store.peekAll('item');
        });
    }
});
```

But unfortunately it's not ideal since it requires to `unloadAll()` *items* before making the request as to ensure that the model only returns freshly fetched records while unloading any cached.

A better solution will probably involve creating a custom adapter specifically for this route and overwriting either the `findAll()` method or `urlForFindAll()`, but I'm not sure how to properly create and import such custom adapter.

Just for testing I overwrote the default `Item` adapter and returned `findAll('item')` in the route's model, and everything worked, the request was prefixed with `/my/`:

```
// adapters/item.js
findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken, snapshotRecordArray) {
  var query, url;
  if (sinceToken) { query = { since: sinceToken }; }

  // prefix url with `my` str
  url = `my${this.buildURL(type.modelName, null, null, 'findAll')}`;
  return this.ajax(url, 'GET', { data: query });
},

// routes/my/item.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('item');
  }
});
```

..but that obviously overwrites all `findAll()` queries for this model, wherein I need to make a custom query only in this route.

Comment: Look at the namespace property on adapters.

Comment: torazaburo, ok I can create a new custom adapter and add a `my` namespace, but how do I import it into this route and use the `findAll` method on it? Since I don't need to namespace all `findAll()` requests for `items` in my app, only this one.

Comment: Make an adapter for the particular model you want it to apply to. You don't import it; Ember will find it.

Comment: @torazaburo, well, as I said, I can't use the default item's adapter, since that will overwrite the behavior everywhere in my codebase. I only need to make this prefixed `my/items` query in this particular route. So I need to create a completely new custom adapter that is not associated with the model. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Adapters are per model only, so it isn't possible to load an adapter just for a route. I believe your solution is already good for the time being.

Comment: It´s a hack but you could simply use store.query to always trigger a GET request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using `adapterOptions` to pass options to the item's adapter using `findAll`:

1) In the route use `adapterOption` to pass prefix to the adapter:

```
return this.store.findAll('item', { adapterOptions: { prefix: 'my' } });
```

2) In ember-cli overwrite item's default adapter with `ember g adapter item`.

3) In the adapter overwrite the default `findAll` to prefix url if such option is passed:

```
// /app/adapters/item.js
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken, snapshotRecordArray) {
    var query, url;
    if (sinceToken) { query = { since: sinceToken }; }

    let prefix = Ember.get(snapshotRecordArray, 'adapterOptions.prefix');
    url = `${prefix || ''}${this.buildURL(type.modelName, null, null, 'findAll')}`;

    return this.ajax(url, 'GET', { data: query });
  },
});
```

4) Success, `this.store.findAll('item', { adapterOptions: { prefix: 'my' } });` will now make a `my/items` instead of `items`!